# Dynamically Carry Values from inputs to Dynamically added new inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently it only adds the value once. I have a list of dropdowns(per this example its just input values that u can manually change) that I change from time to time. When clicking 'add' button, it should carry those values over to the field_wrapper, while dynamically adding new input fields to carry each value.
Meaning, I want it to add each new value selected from "text" and append to each new input text field!
I set the global variables above the function. But not sure why the value only shows up one time, and doesn't add new values each time I click 'add' 
I hope this makes sense!

**Javascript**

```
// Dynamically Add More Input Fields after Add Button //Add to cart
  var maxNum= 20; 
  var addButton = $('.add_button'); 
  var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); 
  var fieldHTML = '<div><input type="text" id="test" value=""/><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button"><img src="remove-icon.png"/></a></div>'; //New input field html
  var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1

  //Once add button is clicked
  $(addButton).click(function(){
      //Check maximum number of input fields
      if(x < maxNum){
          x++;
          var cartID = $('#cID').val(),
          cartd = $('#dID').val(),
          cartP = $('#price').val()
          text=cartID + cartD+ cartP;
          $(wrapper).append(field)
          $('#test').val(text)
      }
  });

  //Once remove button is clicked
  $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).parent('div').remove();
  });
```

**HTML**

```
 <input name="cID" class="form-control" type="text" id="cID" value="">
 <input name="dID" class="form-control" type="text" id="dID" value="">
 <input name="price" class="form-control" type="text" id="price" value="">

 <div class="field_wrapper">
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing to do more simply interpolate the html and add `text` variable as value of `id="test"` but it is better to use class instead of id.

```js
// Dynamically Add More Input Fields after Add Button //Add to cart
  var maxNum= 20; 
  var addButton = $('.add_button'); 
  var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); 
  var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1

  //Once add button is clicked
  $(addButton).click(function(){
      //Check maximum number of input fields
      if(x < maxNum){
          x++;
          var cartID = $('#cID').val(),
          cartd = $('#dID').val(),
          cartP = $('#price').val()
          text=cartID + cartd + cartP;
          $(wrapper).append(`<div><input type="text" id="test" value="${text}"/><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button"><img src="remove-icon.png"/></a></div>`)
      }
  });

  //Once remove button is clicked
  $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).parent('div').remove();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="cID" class="form-control" type="text" id="cID" value="">
 <input name="dID" class="form-control" type="text" id="dID" value="">
 <input name="price" class="form-control" type="text" id="price" value="">

 <div class="field_wrapper">
 <button class="add_button">Add</button>
 </div>
```